# Override Shipping Price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, custom-shipping-method

Is there any way to override Shipping Price by Special User (Customer Service Team) when they place an order for the customer.

I want to add a text box for the Custom Shipping price which will override existing shipping cost to quote when user will go to the next step.

[image]

For Example, I want to make 46.53 to 40.

Comment: is this shipping method coming from one carrier?

Comment: Yes amit. It’s coming from one carrier

Comment: can you please share yours carrier method code?

Comment: Can you specify which shipping method you want to change rate?

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you should set the price to depend on the customer inputed.

with function **setPrice** of **\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method**

The solution is plugin to **Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method** and change value of **price** before set to data['price'];

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method">
        <plugin name="namespace_change_price_of_shipping_rate" type="NameSpace\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method"/>
</type>
```

**NameSpace\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method**

```
namespace NameSpace\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult;

class Method
{

      protected $_customerSession;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession)
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }


    /**
     * Round shipping carrier's method price
     *
     * @param string|float|int $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSetPrice($subject, $price)
    {
        // @TODO returun inputed price
        return $price;
    }


    public function beforeSetCost($subject, $price)
    {
        // @TODO returun inputed price.
        return $price;
    }

    public function beforeSetData($subject, $key, $value){
        if('price' == $key || 'cost' == $key){
                //@TODO set inputed price to value
        }
        return [$key, $value];
    }
}
```

2: Edit your **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html:16** file to Add an input for input custom price

```
<input type="text" attr="'value': customPrice "/>
```

3: Edit shipping javascript file **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js** to add a function that appends **custom price** to shipping data.

```
    selectShippingMethod: function (shippingMethod) {
        selectShippingMethodAction(shippingMethod);
        checkoutData.setSelectedShippingRate(shippingMethod['carrier_code'] + '_' + shippingMethod['method_code']);
        /** @TODO store custom input data to somewhere 
         * for  NameSpace\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method 
         * can get and set to value of variable **price** */
        return true;
    },
```

Comment: Could you please let me know if my requirement is possible https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341013/how-to-calculate-dynamic-shipping-amount-based-on-address-in-magento-2-4

Answer (score 1):

You need to do code like this.
We take example that, you need to price into carrier called "Tablerate".

1. we need to create `di.xml` at following location.

> [Vendor]/[Extension]/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
          <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier\Tablerate" />
    </config>
```

2. create our logic file here.

> [Vendor]/[Extension]/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

class Tablerate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        //Do your logic before this line and return your custom price.
        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add input field in admin for shipping price and apply that to order , how can i do that