# Magento 2: How to add additional custom rate in shipping method?

Tags: magento2, price, shipping-methods

I am not getting here that how can we add additional rate in any shipping method. Do anyone have solution for it?

I have tried to do it with below link's logic but it is not working. Referred link - [Override Shipping Price in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237110/override-shipping-price-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding address rate file in your custom module. Here is the way that how can you add it?

> PackageName/CustomShip/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate" type="PackageName\CustomShip\Model\Rewrite\Quote\Address\Rate" />
</config>
```

> Please create Rate.php file in path - PackageName/CustomShip/Model/rewrite/Quote/Address/Rate.php

```
<?php
 
namespace PackageName\CustomShip\Model\Rewrite\Quote\Address;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class Rate extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate
{
    public function importShippingRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\AbstractResult $rate)
    {
        $addtionalPrice = 10;
        $finalPrice = $rate->getPrice() + $addtionalPrice;

        if ($rate instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
            $this->setCode(
                $rate->getCarrier() . '_error'
            )->setCarrier(
                $rate->getCarrier()
            )->setCarrierTitle(
                $rate->getCarrierTitle()
            )->setErrorMessage(
                $rate->getErrorMessage()
            );
        } elseif ($rate instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method) {
            $this->setCode(
                $rate->getCarrier() . '_' . $rate->getMethod()
            )->setCarrier(
                $rate->getCarrier()
            )->setCarrierTitle(
                $rate->getCarrierTitle()
            )->setMethod(
                $rate->getMethod()
            )->setMethodTitle(
                $rate->getMethodTitle()
            )->setMethodDescription(
                $rate->getMethodDescription()
            )->setPrice(
                $finalPrice
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override below vendor module for flatrate shipping method Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Flatrate" />
    </config>
```

Modify the as per requirement into you cusom file app\code\Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier\Flatrate.php

```
 <?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\OfflineShipping\Carrier;

use Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

/**
 * Flat rate shipping model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Flatrate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'flatrate';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @var ItemPriceCalculator
     */
    private $itemPriceCalculator;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate\ItemPriceCalculator $itemPriceCalculator,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->itemPriceCalculator = $itemPriceCalculator;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $rateResultFactory, $rateMethodFactory, $itemPriceCalculator, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return Result|bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = $this->getFreeBoxesCount($request);
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        /** @var Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        $shippingPrice = $this->getShippingPrice($request, $freeBoxes);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->createResultMethod($shippingPrice);
            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @param int $freeBoxes
     * @return bool|float
     */
    private function getShippingPrice(RateRequest $request, $freeBoxes)
    {
        $shippingPrice = false;

        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'O') {
            // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerOrder($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'I') {
            // per item
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerItem($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false && $request->getPackageQty() == $freeBoxes) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }
        

        if(true){
            $shippingPrice = '33.00';
        }

        return $shippingPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|float $shippingPrice
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method
     */
    private function createResultMethod($shippingPrice)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier('flatrate');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('flatrate');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
        return $method;
    }
}
```